# Wildfly and auto reconnect to the database

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I've got a client, a server and a database. The client communicates with the server via a EJB remote interfaces. As the server - I use a Wildfly 8.2.0. As the database - I use a MySQL. The server communicates with the MySQL via a JPA/Hibernate. When I turn off the MySQL server - the Wildfly throws an exception, of course. But when I turn on the MySQL again - the Wildfly still throws the same [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/2jga18fW). I've to turn off the Wildfly and turn it back that the Wildfly reconnect to the database.

How to set auto reconnect in the Wildfly?

I tried to set auto reconnect in a connection URL: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8` and i tried to add to the standalone-full.xml file which i use, this line: `<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>`, but both solutions don't work.

standalone-full.xml:

```
<!-- ... -->
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF8</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>mysqlDriver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>***</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="mysqlDriver" module="com.mysql">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the validate-on-match value to true in my standalone-full.xml file:

`<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>`

Comment: this enable an old behavior. From the doc:
(https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s13.html)
__<validate-on-match> - Prior to JBoss 4.0.5, connection validation occurred when the JCA layer attempted to match a managed connection. With the addition of <background-validation> this is no longer required. Specifying <validate-on-match> forces the old behavior. NOTE: this is typically NOT used in conjunction with <background-validation>__

Comment: You maybe right @dometec , but I can confirm that on Wildfly 10 you need validate-on-match true otherwise Wildfly will never reconnect successfully to the connection pool if you bounce MySQL. I've tried background validation and is doesn't work. I think this is a bug.

Comment: Setting background-validation worked for me only after I set also background-validation-millis as in @dometec's answer. Wildfly 10.1 and SqlServer here.

Answer (score 27):

This working on Wildfly 8.1:

```
         <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xxxdb" pool-name="xxxxDB" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
          <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
          <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
          <driver>mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar</driver>
          <security>
              <user-name>xxxuser</user-name>
              <password>xxxpassword</password>
          </security>
          <validation>
              <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
              <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
              <background-validation>true</background-validation>
              <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
          </validation>
          <statement>
              <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
          </statement>
        </datasource>
```

Comment: We are using Oracle database and not working this solution, could you please suggest what needs to be done for oracle.

Comment: For oracle the statement should probably be "select 1 from dual"

Answer (score 6):

You can set `<background-validation>` to `true` , because this option has better performance , and set `<validate-on-match>` to `false`

Comment: <background-validation> has been deprecated. Use background-validation-millis instead