# DB Connection is not getting removed from pool when transaction is rolled back during database fail over in Wildfly-17

Tags: java, database-connection, wildfly, rollback

I am using `Wildfly-17` server. I am testing the failover scenario on the Oracle database during ongoing API traffic in Wildfly. 
The steps I performed:

- Oracle RAC DB setup is done and scans IP (Virtual IP) is configured in domain.xml. Also, created 2 database services (named as "pri" and "sec") in the database with preferred service configuration.
- Wildfly server is up and running with my project binaries,
  where DS configuration is:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS" pool-name="jdbc/InventoryDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="false" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.151.5.16:1521/pri</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="AutoCommit">false</connection-property>
    <driver>ojdbc8</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <initial-pool-size>1</initial-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <fair>false</fair>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <security-domain>InventoryDS</security-domain>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <track-statements>false</track-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

- Started load (REST API) using JMeter. All current Db connection is pointing to "pri" service.
- During ongoing traffic, I rebooted one DB node (having "pri" service)

**Expectation:**
The existing DB connections will be removed from the pool and a new connection will be pointing to "sec" service. Hence, minimal impact on ongoing API traffic

**Actual result:** 
It is not removing DB connection from the pool. Next time the same connection is getting used. Due to which the API is getting failed.

**Observation:**
The code is written in such a way that for any exception occurs during API execution, the code set to call setRollbackOnly() method for the transaction (it is a container-managed transaction in EJB).

Due to the transaction rollback, the server is not able to remove the connection from the pool.

When I removed `setRollbackOnly()` from code, then it is able to remove connection from pool and next request will get new connection from "sec" DB service.

## Logs for the reference:

### **Logs with setRollbackOnly() called from API:**

```
2019-09-13 11:01:44,464 TRACE (default task-15) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-4467852c-1046-93-2069714450032188-105a159d-73db02c0-org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction@75128fe0
2019-09-13 11:01:44,464 TRACE (default task-15) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-4467852c-1046-41-2069714450059032-105a159d-73db02c0-
2019-09-13 11:01:44,464 TRACE (default task-15) [TxConnectionListener@105a159d] unregisterConnection: 0 handles left ([])
2019-09-13 11:01:44,464 TRACE (default task-15) isManagedConnectionFree=false mc=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@33bd6c05
2019-09-13 11:01:44,465 TRACE (default task-15) popped object: org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction@75128fe0
2019-09-13 11:01:44,465 TRACE (default task-15) IJTRACER-CachedConnectionManager-NONE-1046-91-2069714451688504-NONE-org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction@75128fe0-java.lang.Throwable:_CALLSTACK|\at_org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManagerImpl.popMetaAwareObject(CachedConnectionManagerImpl.java:283)|\at_org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction.teardown(CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor.java:107)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:60)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)|\at_org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)|\at_com.demo.inventory.ejb3.inventorymgmt.interfaces.IInventoryDetailSessionLocal$$$view355.searchInventory(Unknown_Source)|\at_com.demo.inventory.ejb3.inventorymgmt.sessionfacadeintapi.InventoryOperations.searchInventory(InventoryOperations.java:529)|\at_sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1021.invoke(Unknown_Source)|\at_sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)|\at_java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)|\at_org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:70)|\at_org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)|\at_org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)|\at_com.demo.inventory.aspect.PrePostPlugin.processPrePostEvent(PrePostPlugin.java:125)|\at_sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1020.invoke(Unknown_Source)|\at_sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)|\at_java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)|\at_org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)|\at_org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:44)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)|\at_org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)|\at_org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)|\at_org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)|\at_org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:266)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:184)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:138)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)|\at_org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)|\at_com.sun.proxy.$Proxy250.searchInventory(Unknown_Source)|\at_com.demo.rest.inventory.delegator.InventoryOperationsDelegator.searchInventory(InventoryOperationsDelegator.java:70)|\at_com.demo.rest.inventory.service.InventoryOperationsService.searchInventory(InventoryOperationsService.java:61)|\at_com.demo.rest.inventory.resource.InventoryOperationsResource.searchInventory(InventoryOperationsResource.java:69)|\at_sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1019.invoke(Unknown_Source)|\at_sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)|\at_java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:225)|\at_org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:62)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)|\at_com.demo.rest.core.filter.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:51)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)|\at_org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)|\at_io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)|\at_io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)|\at_io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)|\at_io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)|\at_io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)|\at_org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)|\at_io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)|\at_io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)|\at_io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)|\at_io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)|\at_java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)|\at_java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)|\at_java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)|
2019-09-13 11:01:44,466 TRACE (default task-15) BaseTransaction.setRollbackOnly
2019-09-13 11:01:44,466 TRACE (default task-15) TransactionImple.setRollbackOnly
2019-09-13 11:01:44,466 TRACE (default task-15) TransactionImple.getStatus: javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
2019-09-13 11:01:44,466 TRACE (default task-15) BaseTransaction.rollback
2019-09-13 11:01:44,466 TRACE (default task-15) TransactionImple.rollbackAndDisassociate
2019-09-13 11:01:44,468 TRACE (default task-15) Unlock: HeldByCurrentThread: Yes, Locked: Yes, HoldCount: 1, QueueLength: 0
2019-09-13 11:01:44,468 TRACE (default task-15) Owner: Thread[default task-15,5,main]
2019-09-13 11:01:44,476 TRACE (default task-15) SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion - Class: class org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList HashCode: 40330594 toString: org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList@2676562
2019-09-13 11:01:44,476 TRACE (default task-15) afterCompletion(4) isTrackByTx=true for org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@105a159d[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@33bd6c05 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1568352703782 lastValidated=1568350845750 lastCheckedOut=1568352703818 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject@20796ab0 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@4467852c[pool=jdbc/InventoryDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@1263d5dd[connectionListener=105a159d connectionManager=630b92ae warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS] txSync=null]
2019-09-13 11:01:44,476 TRACE (default task-15) [TxConnectionListener@105a159d] isManagedConnectionFree: true
2019-09-13 11:01:44,476 TRACE (default task-15) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-4467852c-1046-34-2069714462871419-105a159d--
```

### **Logs without setRollbackOnly() from API:**

```
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-588c2c98-1051-93-2069714465486053-3c9e3b2f-23a7ccff-org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.ra.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction@751461b5
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-588c2c98-1051-41-2069714465507047-3c9e3b2f-23a7ccff-
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) [TxConnectionListener@3c9e3b2f] unregisterConnection: 0 handles left ([])
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) isManagedConnectionFree=false mc=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@110a223f
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.getStatus: javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) BaseTransaction.commit
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion - Class: class org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList HashCode: 101703171 toString: org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList@60fde03
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.getStatus: javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.getStatus: javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) delistResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@332d0f3[connectionListener=3c9e3b2f connectionManager=3081dd0c warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c51, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c53, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS > productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS], TMSUCCESS)
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.delistResource ( LocalXAResourceImpl@332d0f3[connectionListener=3c9e3b2f connectionManager=3081dd0c warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c51, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c53, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS > productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS], 67108864 )
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) TransactionImple.getStatus: javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) end(< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c51, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c53, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS >,67108864)
2019-09-13 11:01:44,479 TRACE (default task-17) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-588c2c98-1051-30-2069714465761476-3c9e3b2f-TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a278003:_28cc616e:5d7b227a:c51 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING >-
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) Unlock: HeldByCurrentThread: Yes, Locked: Yes, HoldCount: 1, QueueLength: 0
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) Owner: Thread[default task-17,5,main]
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-588c2c98-1051-11-2069714466239757-3c9e3b2f--
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) returnConnection(3c9e3b2f, true)
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) Destroying returned connection org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@3c9e3b2f[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@110a223f connection handles=0 lastReturned=1568352703828 lastValidated=1568350873622 lastCheckedOut=1568352703856 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject@7b955f13 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@588c2c98[pool=jdbc/InventoryDS] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@332d0f3[connectionListener=3c9e3b2f connectionManager=3081dd0c warned=false currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/InventoryDS] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@384438466{tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a278003:-28cc616e:5d7b227a:c51 status: ActionStatus.COMMITTING > wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=true cancel=false}]
2019-09-13 11:01:44,480 TRACE (default task-17) IJTRACER-jdbc/InventoryDS-588c2c98-1051-70-2069714466500063-3c9e3b2f--
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you want such behavior you should set `check-valid-connection-sql` and `background-validation` to true. See also [Wildfly and auto reconnect to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707650/wildfly-and-auto-reconnect-to-the-database) and

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-database_connection_validation

for documentation.